# Prove that the following function is not continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

We have: 
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2y^4}{x^4+y^8}& (x,y)\ne(0,0)\\
0, & (x,y)=0
\end{cases}$$

We need to prove that $f(x,y)$ is not continuous.

Here is all my steps:

- Consider the sequence $(x_n,y_n)=(\frac{1}{n},0)\rightarrow(0,0)$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$
  $$\Rightarrow f(x_n,y_n)=0\rightarrow 0$$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$
- Consider another sequence $(a_n,b_n)=(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})\rightarrow(0,0)$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$

$$\Rightarrow f(x_n,y_n)=\frac{n^{12}}{n^6}=n^2\rightarrow\infty$$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$

$$\Rightarrow\nexists\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)$$ Therefore $f(x,y)$ isn't continue. Necessary condition to be continue is that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)=0=f(x,y)$ but because $\nexists\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ it is not continuous.

Comment: do you mean continuous?

Comment: we need to show that this function is not continue

Comment: That shows that $f$ is not continuous **in** the origin, not in all its domain.

Comment: I suppose my demonstration is good, is any problem? I want to delete this question if isn't problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one mistake, actually you should have 
$$
f(\frac 1n,\frac 1n)=\frac{\frac 1{n^2}\cdot\frac 1{n^4} }{\frac 1{n^4}+\frac 1{n^8}}=\frac{\frac 1{n^6}}{\frac {n^4+1}{n^8}}=\frac 1{n^6}\cdot\frac {n^8}{n^4+1}=\frac {n^2}{n^4+1}
$$
Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(\frac 1n,\frac 1n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {n^2}{n^4+1}=0$ also.

The correct way is to consider the sequence $(\frac 1{n^2},\frac 1n)\to(0,0)$, we can see that 
$$
f(\frac 1{n^2},\frac 1n)=\frac{\frac 1{n^4}\cdot\frac 1{n^4} }{\frac 1{n^8}+\frac 1{n^8}}=\frac{\frac 1{n^8}}{\frac 2{n^8}}=\frac 12
$$
so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(\frac 1{n^2},\frac 1n)=\frac 12\ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Take the curve $$f(ax^2,bx)=\frac{a^2x^4\cdot b^4x^4}{a^4x^8+b^8x^8}=\frac{a^2b^4}{a^4+b^8}$$ This is largely enough (infinitely many distinct limits on the origin).